# behaviour difference between @Configuration and @Component

Tags: spring

Is there any difference between behaviour of `@Configuration` and `@Component`annotation in Spring framework?

Is there any situation when changing `@Configuration` to `@Component` will change program's behaviour?

I did a few experiments and from what I see so far, they always work the same.
Notice that I'm interested specifically in the difference of behaviour - I already know that the two annotations are usually used in different situations.

Comment: Ses "@Bean lite mode" in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Answer (score 3):

Your `@Configuration` class can be annotated also with [@ComponentScan](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)

> we use the @ComponentScan annotation along with @Configuration annotation to specify the packages that we want to be scanned

If you change to `@Component` it won't work as expected

See also [difference between @Configuration and @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174669/what-is-the-difference-between-configuration-and-component-in-spring)

> @Configuration is also a @Component but a @Component cannot act like a @Cofinguration

Answer (score 2):

While they both make annotated classes beans, they serve different purposes.

Treat a class with `@Configuration` as a part of your application context where you define beans. Usually, you have `@Bean` definitions in your `@Configuration` class.

`@Component` annotation, on the other hand, means that your class IS a bean itself and that it.

So, for example you need a bean `MyService`.
You can define it in two ways:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {

   @Bean
   public MyService myService(){
      return new MyServiceImpl();
   }
}
```

or just

```
@Component
public class MyServiceImpl {
   ...
}
```

So, when you use your `@Configuration` as a configuration, adding things specific to it (`@ComponentScan, @Bean, ...)` it would have a different behaviour and it won't work with just `@Component` instead.